# Oracle .NET provider ORA-01735

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I'm calling the following script from .NET using Oracle.DataAccess.Client

```
using (var dbCommand = oracleConnection.CreateCommand())
{
    dbCommand.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE USERS MODIFY (USER_ID NUMBER(18,0));";
    dbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

But I'm getting the exception:

> ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option

which is strange because the command

```
ALTER TABLE USERS MODIFY (USER_ID NUMBER(18,0));
```

works when called from Oracle SQL Developer tool.

Comment: Try removing the semicolon? I haven't used Oracle in a while, but I seem to remember the C# clients were funny about that.

Comment: Your column is keyword ?

Comment: @mason Thank you, it works without the semicolon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
dbCommand.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE USERS MODIFY (USER_ID NUMBER(18,0));";
```

should be

```
dbCommand.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE USERS MODIFY (USER_ID NUMBER(18,0))";
```

When using Oracle clients for .NET, Oracle does not like the semicolon in the command.

Comment: It's not the client that complains. It's a *server* message

Comment: There are several layers which produce error messages. It may well be OCI layer (client side) already complains, but that is just a detail.

Comment: @mason no. Just like `GO` is a command that only scripting tools use to delimit commands sent to SQL Server, `SQL Developer` may be using `;` to delimit commands sent to Oracle. I'd bet that you'd get the same error if you tried with JDBC

Comment: No, @PanagiotisKanavos, that is nonsense. `;` is the Oracle statement delimiter as documented. It is not a script tool separator. The problem is probably the way the SQL and PL/SQL engine are split and there is a different handling of statements between them.

Comment: @PatrickHofman which is what I said more or less. Or Oracle doesn't like `;` in *some* SQL commands. In any case, it's has nothing to do with the client

Comment: But it has nothing to do with scripting tools as you state. It is part of the language.